# Magento: product pages (only) throw error

Tags: php, url, magento, url-rewriting, product

So I've created a new install of Magento 1.4.1.1, set up the whole system again from scratch, installed the theme, and brought in the products from a csv file from previous install (same version).

All is working well now, homepage, category pages, account pages - all good.

When you click on a PRODUCT, to go to the product page, Magento throws the "There has been an error..." page.  Every product, simple, config, and I made a couple of new products too, these give the same error.

Have not edited the .htaccess file, have flushed and re-indexed everything.  Can anyone recommend something to try?  I've got a hunch it's a URL re-write issue, but I havent really done anything to cause this.

Before importing the products I cleared the url fields in the csv file too, to allow the server to make new ones.

Urgent help required - am very greatful for your help.

Comment: Please paste the error also so we could recommend the solution for the error. You can find error by number from var/report folder

Comment: fixed it - had the wrong combo of magento install and the theme file.